# How to set Playwright Source root directory via PLAYWRIGHT_JAVA_SRC environment variable when source collection is enabled -How to set it for linux

Tags: java

I'm trying to run my  Playwright trace using java and I'm getting the below error, I'm not sure what I'm missing out and I'm running my code in eclipse

```
final Browser.NewContextOptions browserContextOptions = new Browser.NewContextOptions().setIgnoreHTTPSErrors(true).setViewportSize(width,height);
        context = browser.newContext(browserContextOptions);
        //context = browser.newContext(new Browser.NewContextOptions().setViewportSize(width, height));

        // Start tracing before creating / navigating a page.
        context.tracing().start(new Tracing.StartOptions()
                .setScreenshots(true)
                .setSnapshots(true)
                .setSources(true));
        page = context.newPage();
```

I am getting the following error

> [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.4.0 FAILED CONFIGURATION:
> @BeforeMethod doLaunchBrowser
> com.microsoft.playwright.PlaywrightException: Source root directory
> must be specified via PLAYWRIGHT_JAVA_SRC environment variable when
> source collection is enabled  at
> com.microsoft.playwright.impl.TracingImpl.startImpl(TracingImpl.java:94)
> at
> com.microsoft.playwright.impl.TracingImpl.lambda$start$0(TracingImpl.java:68)
> at
> com.microsoft.playwright.impl.LoggingSupport.lambda$withLogging$0(LoggingSupport.java:36)
> at
> com.microsoft.playwright.impl.LoggingSupport.withLogging(LoggingSupport.java:47)
> at
> com.microsoft.playwright.impl.ChannelOwner.withLogging(ChannelOwner.java:85)
> at
> com.microsoft.playwright.impl.LoggingSupport.withLogging(LoggingSupport.java:35)
> at
> com.microsoft.playwright.impl.TracingImpl.start(TracingImpl.java:68)
> at
> com.united_arab_bank.base.BasePage.doLaunchBrowser(BasePage.java:91)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)   at
> org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
> at
> org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
> at
> org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:385)
> at
> org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:321)
> at
> org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.runConfigMethods(TestInvoker.java:700)
> at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:527)
> at
> org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
> at
> org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
> at
> org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
> at
> org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
> at
> org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
> at
> org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)   at
> org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)     at
> org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)    at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)   at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)   at
> org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)     at
> org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)  at
> org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)     at
> org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)   at
> org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
> at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
> at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue on macOS.

For mac ONLY, add the following line to `~/.zshrc` file.

`export PLAYWRIGHT_JAVA_SRC=/usr/libexec/java_home`

Don't forget to close your current terminal and open a new one in order to read the updated env variables.